# tomcat server issue with angular api request

Tags: java, angular, tomcat

**Here is the body message I'm receiving from angular. Would like to understand which is the root cause of this issue. I'm not really sure what part of tomcat or angular is creating this issue. Any guesses?**

```
</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> java.lang.NullPointerException</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1232)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:271)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:577)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:915)
    com.idem.api.SampleService.getSampleList(SampleService.java:263)
    com.idem.api.SampleService.getAllSamples(SampleService.java:147)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1232)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:271)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.33</h3></body></html>
```

EDIT: I was able to fix the problem it seems. The problem was that I was using a JDBC singleton for all my API requests, but the way that JDBC is set up is that the DB connection using a statement object to run its queries. Therefore when I try to use multiple requests, the requests sometimes come into conflict when the statement is still in use, but another request wants to grab it instead.

Answer (score 0):

With the information given it is difficult to judge on the **real** root cause. The presented traces shows a NullPointerException when reading from a database.
The call seems to come from `com.idem.api.SampleService.getAllSamples`. I would assume that this is part of your Java code (deployed to Tomcat).

On the interface level (between Angular/ backend) you should introduce some validation, e.g. for unexpected null values passed from the Angular frontend to the backend. This would help to clarify where the real root cause is.